# Adding many SVG or Icon Fonts to a page - Performance

Tags: html, svg, retina

I was going to use SVG for all the many icons I use on my site but have read that using tons of SVG will slow down a site. I basically have tons of search results on my website and each result has like 7  icons on them. Another developer helping me with the project told me to use images because all the SVG would dramatically slow the page down and possibly freeze, but I would like to use SVG for HD phone / retina support.

Could I use icon fonts instead of imbedding the long svg code for every element, or do icon fonts use the same amount of memory since they basically are SVG, or do they require less memory?

If Icon fonts take the same amount and maybe slow my site down / freeze it then maybe the only option for adding lots of amounts of icons to a site is just images and media queries for adding the larger icons for retina..:(..??

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a senior dev and he said icon fonts are same size as normal font files. How come people arent seeing my posts recently.